# scenekit skybox flickering on camera movement

Tags: ios, scenekit

the skybox has high resolution images of 1500x1500 for retina

```
SCNScene *scene = [SCNScene scene];

scene.background.contents = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"left.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"left.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"top.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"botom.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"front.png"]];
```

and the camera is configured as:

```
_cameraNode                 = [SCNNode node];
_cameraNode.camera          = [SCNCamera camera];
_cameraNode.position        = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 10000);
_cameraNode.camera.xFov     = 55;
_cameraNode.camera.zFar     = 2100000;
_cameraNode.camera.aperture = 1/50;
```

I'm moving the camera by its z value by 100 incrementally. When the camera reaches around 252000 the skybox starts to flicker as if it zooms in and out. the problem gets worse if the camera goes further until scene is black( black is the background color of the SCNView). How to avoid such flickering and being able to the camera in very bis scene? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: yes i did try and it worked. i reworked my 3D scene where the measurements und object size were shrinked down and it stopped flickering. I also learn that one must not use real world object size. it would be mush better to shrink down all objects proportionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comments, I reworked my 3D scene where the measurements und object size were shrinked down. I also learned that one must not use real world object size. It would be much better to shrink down all objects proportionally. One do not need to create huge scene with real world size and measurement. Shrinking down will also need smaller texture, and that can be useful for memory optimisation. Since apply these changes, I haven't seen any flickering.

Comment: Accepting theoretical answers doesn't help others. Please share some code of your resolution so that everyone can benefit.

Comment: The 3D objects were modelled by 3D authoring tools. so the (objective c) code or Xcode were not involved.  If you have modelled all your objects then you should be careful about your geometry size and proportion to other objects. for instance, if a wall is 3 meters high then a mouse would be 0.05 meter in height. so one should think about those sizes and measurements. (I suppose you are using a modelling tool to create your mouse and wall. one could use code only to model the geometry, but thats another story. )

Comment: @HashmatKhalil Would Scaling the models down with Code or scene editor help on this ?

Comment: I had modelled my assests with scenekit. I would recommend to scale assets with your modelling tools, e.g., if your model is say 1 meter in height and the texture is fine for that height but it won't be good for 10 cm shrinked one.it will use a lot of memory. but if you don't have that huge scaling ratio, then its alright to scale models with code.